# Certificate based client authentication in iOS does not work until i restart the application

Tags: ios, nsurlcredential

When I download p12 file from server and set it to NSURLCredential like this:

```
- (NSURLCredential *)getCredential 
{
     NSURLCredential *credential = nil;
     NSString *thePath = //Certificate path
     NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] 

initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (__bridge  CFDataRef)PKCS12Data;

OSStatus status = 1; // an error
SecIdentityRef myIdentity;
SecTrustRef myTrust;
if (PKCS12Data)
    status = extractIdentityAndTrust(inPKCS12Data, &myIdentity, &myTrust); 

if (status == noErr) {
    SecCertificateRef myCert = NULL;
    status = SecIdentityCopyCertificate (myIdentity, &myCert);  
    if (status == noErr) {
        SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509(); 
        SecCertificateRef certArray[1] = { myCert };
        CFArrayRef myCerts = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)certArray, 1, NULL);
        status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(myCerts, myPolicy, &myTrust);   

        SecTrustResultType trustResult;
        if (status == noErr) {
            status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);
        }
        if (status == noErr) {
            credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:myIdentity
                                                certificates:(__bridge NSArray *)myCerts
                                                 `enter code here`persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
            }
            CFRelease(myCerts); 
        }
    }

        return credential;
    }
```

//extractIdentityAndTrust method

```
OSStatus extractIdentityAndTrust(CFDataRef inPKCS12Data, SecIdentityRef *outIdentity, SecTrustRef *outTrust)
```

{

```
OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;

NSString* password = gDataManager.certPass;//CFSTR("qqqqq11");
const void *keys[] =   { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
const void *values[] = { (__bridge  const void *)(password) };
CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, optionsDictionary, &items);
if (securityError == 0) {
    CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex (items, 0);
    const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
    tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);
    *outIdentity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
    const void *tempTrust = NULL;
    tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);
    *outTrust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;
} else {
    NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:securityError userInfo:nil];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}

if (optionsDictionary)
    CFRelease(optionsDictionary);

return securityError;
```

}

When I do this it does not work.  But if I close and open the application its work fine.  Is someone has idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you using `getCredential` ?

Comment: I call it in **connection: didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:**  delegate method and then do this    **[[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];**
"credential"  the returned value of **getCredential**

Comment: Is it actually called ?

Comment: **connection: didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:**  this delegate method calls only one time. But first time don't need the authentication. How can i clear cache or what i need to do that **connection: didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:** calls again?

Comment: You don't need to clear cache, make sure your services require authentication by returning a proper status code and www-authenticate header. The method is supposed to be called for every request requiring authentication and having it called once might be sufficient. However it is impossible to tell why your credentials are properly applied only after you restart the app without seeing the code where you apply it.